# spark structured streaming using different schema for each row based on message type

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

The application is streaming from a kafka topic that gets messages with different structure.  The only way to know which structure it is, is to use the message key.  Is there a way to apply a schema based on the message type.  Such as use a function in the from_json method and pass the key into this fuction.